# JavaFX: тема Darcula

Tags: css, javafx, themes

Где скачать `.css` файл темы **Darcula** (как в *IntellijIDEA*) для JavaFX?

Comment: Вы имели в виду `Darcula`?

Comment: @selya да, хочу скачать ей .css.

Comment: Все ведь зависит от того, где вы собираетесь эту тему использовать...

Comment: @selya я же написал что в JavaFX.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не придал значения заголовку. Добавьте это в сам вопрос, чтобы понятнее было)

Comment: @selya На этом сайте я уже был, но там нет .css

Comment: Что-то я вообще не понял, тема то какая? Dracula или Darcula это две разные темы?

Comment: @VladSpirin Darcula

Comment: @VladSpirin в intellij тема darcula,  так что она)

Comment: есть такое для VSC: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=trinm1709.dracula-theme-from-intellij

Comment: В гугле полно всего этого, зачем то тут на стаке такой вопрос?